# How can Apache use Py3 instesd of Py2?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

How can Apache use Python/3.x instesd of Python/2.x ?

I'm now trying to set up Django application on server with Py3.
The command `python manage.py runserver` was successful.
Then I tried to use `Apache` and `mod_wsgi` but I got `Internal Server Error`.

The error logs said that

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30732] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

but the default python was Py3.

```
# python -V
Python 3.5.1
```

I wondered the error would be fixed  when apache use Py3. How about you?
How can I specify Py3?

## Start command

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

## Full error logs

```
$ tailf  /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
[Thu Jul 21 15:32:20.626731 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 30732] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 21 15:32:20.627378 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 30732] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jul 21 15:32:20.629557 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30732] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 21 15:32:20.629580 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30732] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.940196 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30732] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.981414 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 30777] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.993034 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 30778] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.993935 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 30778] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.996832 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30778] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 21 15:37:31.996866 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30778] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
```

## environment

```
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) 
mod_wsgi/3.4
Python 3.5.1
Django 1.9
CentOS 7.1
```

Comment: Declare every first script line `#! /usr/bin/python` to `#! /where/your/python/binary` but i haven't any idea about of `django` errors.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I created the simbolic link below but I got the same error.
`
$ ll /usr/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          42 Jul 21 17:36 python -> /usr/local/python/python-3.5.1/bin/python3
`

Comment: Did you enable `CGI` and define `CGI_PATH_DIRECTIVES` on APACHE ?

Comment: I can change Apache Settings. But I don't know about `CGI_PATH_DIRECTIVES`. Would you give me more information or some website url?

Comment: Server work with more directory design. like this `/var/www/your_dom.com/htdocs/`. And `your_dom.com.conf` got `Directory` definition, so need define handler under this header. What can run which ? Check this : https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts  Don't forget your server(Apache) need every directories definition for security.

Comment: Thank you. I try to research it.

Comment: Suggestions for setting up CGI or using a #! line are totally irrelevant as that is not how mod_wsgi works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using compiled **mod_wsgi**, you need to compile it against the appropriate Python binary for the version you want to use, or it'll default to the system Python version (still typically 2.x, unfortunately). For example:

```
wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
make
make install
```

Good luck!

Comment: Version 4.4.21 is old even at this point in time. Right now the latest is 4.5.3.

Comment: Thank you. I installed mod_wsgi-4.5.3 with `--with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5`. And when I tried to `systemctl restart httpd.service`, I had an error `httpd[16435]: httpd: Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared obj...ile or directory`. I'm now searching about `ld.so.conf`.

Comment: Can you amend your answer with your new Apache config?